# Hibernate: rename autogenerated Id in a @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a MySQL database with two tables, `contacts` and `addresses`. The table `addresses` contains a column `contactid` of type big integer to connect with the `contact` table.

I have the following entities in Hibernate with a bidirectional OneToMany - ManyToOne relationship. The problem is that the `@ManyToOne` relationship creates another `contact_id` column of type integer in my datatabase. I would like to use the already existing `contactid` column and not have `contact_id` so I was thinking I should rename the autogenerated `contact_id` column to `contactid` but I don't know if this is possible...

Is there any way to solve this without modifying the database?

Thanks in advance.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="contacts")
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="contact")
    private List<Address> addresses= new ArrayList<Address>();

    // getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name="addresses")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="postalcode")
    private String postalcode;

    @ManyToOne
    private Contact contact;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` along with your `@ManyToOne` in `Address`.

By adding the `mappedBy` to `addresses` you are letting the child to own the relation ship. When you mention the `JoinColumn` you are telling that what is the columns that hold the actual relationship in DB.

Also, you were talking about `contact_id` but I couldn't see that in your mapping.

Comment: The @JoinColumn annotation is what I needed. `contactid` was the column already existing in the database which I wanted to map, and `contact_id` an autogenerated column as a result of the @ManyToOne annotation. Using `@JoinColumn(name="contactid")` solved the problem.